# Cannot fill my R for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, apply

so I am working on R with a matrix as following:

```
diff_0
             SubPop0-1,   SubPop1-1,   SubPop2-1,    SubPop3-1,  SubPop4-1,
SubPop0-1,           NA           NA           NA            NA          NA
SubPop1-1,  0.003403100           NA           NA            NA          NA
SubPop2-1,  0.005481177 -0.002070277           NA            NA          NA
SubPop3-1,  0.002216444  0.005946314  0.001770977            NA          NA
SubPop4-1,  0.010344845  0.007151529  0.004237316 -0.0021275130          NA
```

... but bigger ;-).

This is a matrix of pairwise genetic differenciation between each SubPop from 0 to 4. I would like to obtain a mean differenciation value for each subPop.

For instance, for SubPop-0, the mean would just correspond to the mean of the 4 values from column 1. However for SubPop-2, this would be the mean of the 2 values in line 3 and the 2 value in column 3, since this is a demi-matrix.

I wanted to write a for loop to compute each mean value for each SubPop, taking this into account. I tried the following:

```
Mean <- for (r in 1:nrow(diff_0)) {
    mean(apply(cbind(diff_0[r,], diff_0[,r]), 1, sum, na.rm=T))
 }
```

First this isolates each line and column of index [r], whose values refer to the same SubPop r. 'sum' enable to gather these values and eliminate 'NA's. Finally I get the mean value for my SubPop r. I was hoping my for loop would give me with value for each index r, which would be a SubPop.

However, eventhough my `mean(apply(cbind(diff_0[r,], diff_0[,r]), 1, sum, na.rm=T))`, if run alone with a fixed r value between 1 and 5, does give me what I want; well the 'for loop' itself only returns an empty vector.

Something like `for (r in 1:nrow(diff_0)) { print(diff_0[r,1]) }` also works, so I do not understand what is going on.

This is a trivial question but I could not find an answer on the internet! Although I know I am probably missing the obvious :-)...

Thank you very much, 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, based on what you want to do (and if I understand everything correctly) there are several ways of doing this.
The one that comes to my mind now is just making your lower triangular matrix to an "entire matrix" (i.e. fill the upper triangle with the transpose of the lower triangle) and then do row- or column-wise means
My R is running right now on something else, so I can't check my code but this should work

```
diff = diff_0
diff[upper.tri(diff)] = t(diff_0[lower.tri(diff)]) #This step might need some work
```

As I said, my R is running right now so I can't check the correctness of the last line - I might be confused with some transposes there, so I'd appreciate any feedback on whether it actually worked or not.
You can then either set the diagonal values to 0 or alternatively add na.rm  = TRUE to the mean statement

```
mean_diffs = apply(diff,2,FUN = function(x)mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

that should work

Also: Yes, your code does not work, because the assignment is not in the for loop. This should work:

```
means = rep(NA, nrow(diff_0)
for (r in 1:length(means)){
    means[r] = mean(apply(cbind(diff_0[r,], diff_0[,r]), 1, sum, na.rm=T))
```

But in general for loops are not what you want to do in R

Comment: Thank you very much :-) I did not know about upper/lower.tri, this is indeed very useful! 

diff_0[lower.tri(diff)] returns a numeric vector, so the transposition does not exactly match with the actual semi-matrix, but I just need to spent a bit more time on this!

Also thank you for your feedback on my for loop! That is right, it is better to factorize as much as possible, know that I know this upper.tri function I might try to make this work another way!

Comment: (By the way your corrected code for the loop does work perfectly, thanks again!!)

Comment: @Chrys Yes, it is supposed to return a numeric vector. If you then assign this vector to a matrix with the right dimension (i.e. the upper triangular matrix) it will fill this matrix by columns.
If my answer helped, feel free to mark it as the correct answer (the green tick mark next to my answer)

Comment: This is true, the only issue being that since the upper matrix is filled column by column, we lose the symmetry of the matrix. There is sure a way to fill it row by row! Unfortunately I will not be able to keep looking for tonight, but this was anyway really helpful and I will be right back as soon as I find a way to change the way to fill the upper matrix (except if someone does find before I do, which is of high probability ;-) ) 

Thanks again everyone!

Comment: ... Ok in the end this was easy! Just the other way around:

`diff <- t(diff_0)
diff[lower.tri(diff)] <- diff_0[lower.tri(diff_0)]`

in order to fill the lower matrix rather than the upper one.

Comment: @Chrys Yeah, I figured it would be something stupid that's not working...
Kudos on figuring it out though! And thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution...

```
for(i in 1:nrow(diff_0)) {

    k<-mean(cbind(as.numeric(diff_0[,i]),as.numeric(diff_0[i,])),na.rm=T)
    if(i==1) {

    data_mean <- k
    }else{
    data_mean <- rbind(data_mean,k)
    }
}

colnames(data_mean) <-  "mean"
rownames(data_mean) <- c("SubPop0","SubPop1","SubPop2","SubPop3","SubPop4")

data_mean

               mean
SubPop0 0.005361391
SubPop1 0.003607666
SubPop2 0.002354798
SubPop3 0.001951555
SubPop4 0.004901544
```

Comment: Thank you very much Maydin! This is another interesting way to proceed!